# What are the differences of valarray in gcc and msvc (or Linux and Windows)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, g++, valarray

I experience different behavior of valarray in Windows and Linux. Does anyone know about this or know where to look at? It is obvious, the one version working on both system is correct C++, but why does the other works in Windows? Are there more differences in the implementation of valarray?

Example of Code working on MSVC/Windows but not on gcc/Linux:

```
    valarray<signed short> myValues;
    for(size_t s = 0; s < 10; s++)
    {
        slice dataSlice(1, 1, 1);
        // on Linux, this slice operation gives me a segmentation fault
        myValues= RawData[dataSlice];
    }
```

I tracked it down to fix the code like this for the gcc/Linux version:

```
    for(size_t s = 0; s < 10; s++)
    {
        slice dataSlice(1, 1, 1);
        valarray<signed short> myValues = RawData[dataSlice];
    }
```

The gcc/Linux versions expectes the l-value (myValues) is initialized already. This does not seem to be necessary on MSVC/Windows. I could call `myValues.resize(1)` on Linux and it works as well.

Now, does anyone knows about the differences exactly or a resource on the internet? Are there best practices how to work with the valarray?

Software versions:

- Windows 7, MS Visual Studio 2010 SP1, Visual C++ Compiler 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
- Lubuntu 14.04 64 Bit on Virtual Machine, GNU Make 3.81, GCC 4.8.2

Thanks everyone.

---

**Update: Detailed code example.** Does compile. The first example gives segmentation fault in Linux, but works well in Windows.

```
// This example compiles both on Windows with MSVC and on Linux with GCC.
// It gives a segmentation fault in Linux.
// It gives the expected output on Windows.

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  //init base data

  std::valarray<signed short> myData(10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    myData[i] = i;
  }

  std::valarray<signed short> myValues;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    myValues = myData[std::slice(0, i, 1)];
    std::cout << "myValues: ";

    for (size_t k = 0; k < myValues.size(); k++)
    {  
        std::cout << myValues[k] << ",";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The following example works well on Linux and Windows. Note the declaration and therfore initialization of myValues inside the for loop, right where the slicing is done.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  //init base data

  std::valarray<signed short> myData(10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    myData[i] = i;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    std::valarray<signed short> myValues = myData[std::slice(0, i, 1)];
    std::cout << "myValues: ";

    for (size_t k = 0; k < myValues.size(); k++)
    {  
        std::cout << myValues[k] << ",";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
myValues:
myValues: 0,
myValues: 0,1,
myValues: 0,1,2,
myValues: 0,1,2,3,
myValues: 0,1,2,3,4,
myValues: 0,1,2,3,4,5,
myValues: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,
myValues: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
myValues: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
```

Comment: Can you do a complete example that can be compiled? And also, which version of g++ are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> `valarray.assign/8`:
>
> ```
> valarray<T>& operator=(const slice_array<T>&);
> valarray<T>& operator=(const gslice_array<T>&);
> valarray<T>& operator=(const mask_array<T>&);
> valarray<T>& operator=(const indirect_array<T>&);
> ```
>
> *Requires:* The length of the array to which the argument refers equals `size()`.

You create `myValues` as an empty `valarray` with size 0. Precondition for using `valarray<T>& operator=(const slice_array<T>&);` is not met.

Replace

```
myValues = myData[std::slice(0, i, 1)];
```

with

```
auto s = std::slice(0, i, 1);
myValues.resize(s.size());
myValues = myData[s];
```

or

```
myValues = std::valarray<signed short>(myData[std::slice(0, i, 1)]);
```

and it will work.

What I don't understand yet is why `slice_array<T> operator[](slice slicearr)` is chosen instead of `valarray<T> operator[](slice slicearr) const`.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that documentation snippet as well. And it is clear to me, why it did not work. But my question is: Why is the different behavior from Windows to Linux and where are other differences between the systems?

Comment: Microsoft standard library implementation resizes the array in `valarray<T>& operator=(const slice_array<T>&);`, which is not required by standard. It's strange, that `myValues.resize(1)` helps for all cases, I assume it'll fail for arrays of greater sizes too.

Comment: This seems obvious. What do you mean by "why `slice_array<T> operator[](slice slicearr)` is chosen instead of `valarray<T> operator[](slice slicearr) const`"?

Comment: `valarray<T>::operator[]` is called in expression `myData[std::slice(0, i, 1)]`. There are two overloads - `const` one is returning `valarray` and non-const one is returning `slice_array`. If first one was chosen you wouldn't have to resize destination `valarray` before assignment.

Comment: I am using `valarray` cause `slice_array` is an intermediate type only and I think it is cleanier not create references to intermediate types. I don't know if it really matters.

Comment: I was talking about overload resolution during compile time. Why compiler chooses specific version of overloaded `operator[]`.